# Solidworks double helixes with variable pitch on cone (like a candy)

Tags: solidworks

I try for several days to create a helicoidal surface with variable pitch applied on a cone (like a candy) or exactly like this : http://www.antennamagus.com/database/antennas/antenna_page.php?id=47

I succeeded in drawing the helixes, but I don't manage to fill or extrude between the 3D helixes sketchs. I tried to use boundary surface, filled surface or other methods... however Solidworks returns beautiful but different shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question here : https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/39833